# Db singleton class failing

Tags: php, database, class, singleton

I have a Db access class that I want to be a singleton.
However, I keep getting this error:

```
Accessing static property Db::$connection as non static  
    in /srv/www/htdocs/db_mysql.php on line 41"    
(line 41 is marked below)
```

Here is the code:

```
Class Db {
  // debug mode
  var $debug_mode = false;
  //Hostname - localhost
  var $hostname = "localhost";
  //Database name
  var $database = "db_name";
  //Database Username
  var $username = "db_user";
  //Database Password
  var $password = "db_pwd";

  private static $instance;

  //connection instance
  private static $connection;

  public static function getInstance() {
    if (!self::$instance) {
      self::$instance = new Db;
      self::$instance->connect();
    } //!self::$instance
    return self::$instance;
  } // function getInstance()

  /*
   * Connect to the database
   */
  private function connect() {
    if (is_null($this->hostname))
      $this->throwError("DB Host is not set,");
    if (is_null($this->database))
      $this->throwError("Database is not set.");
    $this->connection = @mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password); // This is line 41
    if ($this->connection === FALSE)
      $this->throwError("We could not connect to the database.");
    if (!mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->connection))
      $this->throwError("We could not select the database provided.");
  } // function connect()

  // other functions located here...

} // Class Db
```

It seems that the check for the static variable $instance in the getInstance() function is failing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why does `$connection` need to be static?  You should be able to make it a regular member variable since there will only be one instance of this thing anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have decalred `$connection` as static:

`private static $connection;`

however you try to access it using `$this`:

`$this->connection = ...` ( line 41)

and that is why you get an error. you should access it like using `self`

`self::$connection = ...` ( corrected line 41 )

OR remove `static` from declaration `$connection`:

`private $connection;`

BTW: just below this line you have again `$this->connection === FALSE` and again in `if (!mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->connection))`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$this->connection` rather than `self::$connection`